# Steam stays in system language

Tags: steam, macos

I have Steam for Mac and every time the app updates, the language of the entire thing is set back to Spanish, my system language, and only changes after a million tries of setting the preferences. Opting out of the beta didn't help either.

Comment: Have you submitted a bug report? This definitely seems like a bug, and ultimately a fix will be better than any workaround people here can provide.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was discouraged from submitting because of the noncommunication.

Comment: At least this question is the very first result for “steam "system language"” on DuckDuckGo. Maybe that'll bring some people who can add knowledge to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a thread on the Steam Community Forums:
http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/2/360671352681228444/?ctp=2

Look like it's a problem that affects everyone with the latest versions of both OS-X (El Capitan) and Steam (Aug. 16 2016 patch).